# Synchronized Realm: How to deal with non-additive migration?

Tags: realm

According to [TFM](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/index.html?io/realm/SyncConfiguration.html), `Synchronized Realms only support additive migrations which can be detected and performed automatically, ...`

When my model changes in a non-additive way (particularly during development), is there any streamlined way to abandon my data and run with the new model?

IE: Do I have to manually delete the Realm files on the server and every client?

Comment: I've heard you have to create an entirely new Sync Realm, and copy things over manually, using a shared schema -  as for how you'd do that in Realm-Java for example, I'm honestly not sure. You'd need new classes for the old schema and the new schema at the same time, and mappers inbetween

Comment: You're probably right, but not really what I'm looking for -- I clarified my question to be more specific.  I want a straightforward way to modify my model, and I don't care about retaining the data already in the realm.

Comment: https://realm.io/webinar/2016-11-10-realm-mobile-platform-overview/ 43:45, you'll probably just specify the `file()` it goes to and delete the previous one manually, yes

Comment: Somewhat gross, but acceptable as a workaround.  I'll file a feature request.  Would you mind posting as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Realm Webinar 43:45](https://realm.io/webinar/2016-11-10-realm-mobile-platform-overview/), **additive** migrations in synchronized Realm are automatic, but **destructive** migrations in synchronized Realm are... well, pretty much as manual as it gets.

You need to create a new Realm file, and if you want to retain elements from the old Realm, then you'd have to copy them over by defining the old schema with the same class names and specified as RealmModule, the new one, and then define the mapping inbetween and copy them over.

Of course, any "destructive schema change" can be portrayed as an entirely new class that only contains a subset of the previous class, and then you can map the classes over with a retained schema within the same Realm file.

---

Considering you do not want to retain the old elements, you can just create a new Realm by specifying a new `file()` parameter for the configuration, that way it counts as a new empty Realm file with a whole new schema.

Comment: Thanks.  [Feature requested here](https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/61).